# Unused method parameters should be removed (squid:S1172) false positive using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, sonarlint, false-positive, method-parameters

I have a working method that uses parameter as a lambda expression

```
private BiConsumer<List<String>, Properties> handleList(Properties p) {
    return (list, prop) -> executeSubList(list, prop);
}
```

For `p` I'm getting a false positive warning from SonarLint

```
Unused method parameters should be removed (squid:S1172)
```

If I change `prop` to `p` I'm getting a compile error

> Lambda expression's parameter p cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope

Is there a real issue or is it a false positive check when using a method parameter as a lambda parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is real. This method returns a `BiConsumer` that runs `executeSubList` on a pair or `List<String>` and `Properties` arguments, but does so regardless of `p`. You could just remove it:

```java
private BiConsumer<List<String>, Properties> handleList() {
    // p was never used, and can just be removed -------^
    return (list, prop) -> executeSubList(list, prop);
}
```

Comment: Good catch, the issue is real - but it is another one than stated (should be "unused parameter").

Comment: @user7294900 A `BiConsumer` consumes two things, hence the name. So the method returns you an object that can be used to consume a `List<String>` and a `Properties`. So `BiConsumer<List<String, Properties> consumer = handleList();` and then `consumer.accept(myList, myProperties);`.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is totally correct.

However, another take on solving this problem is to create a `Consumer` instead of a `BiConsumer`. The parameter `p` would then be used as the parameter to `executeSubList()`:

```
private Consumer<List<String>> handleList(Properties p) {
  return (list) -> executeSubList(list, p);
}
```

Whether this or the solution provided in the accepted answer is the best way to go is dependant on how the surrounding code looks and how the method is to be used.